# Mapping a new column in a pandas dataframe based on columns in another dataframe which share a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

As it usually goes for pandas questions, it was difficult coming up with a concise enough title so people can know what I am asking about without it being too long, but hopefully it is sufficient. I will provide a simplifed example of what am trying to do, as my current working data set is extremely large.

Consider the following simple dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 5 ],
                   [1, 10],
                   [2, 20],
                   [0, 10],
                   [1, 0 ],
                   [2, 15]], columns = ["ID", "val"])
```

Which creates the following dataframe `df`:

```
   ID  val
0   0    5
1   1   10
2   2   20
3   0   10
4   1    0
5   2   15
```

I would like to take this dataframe and append a new column which are the mapped values of a column of another dataframe I call `df_map`, which looks for example like the following:

```
df_map = pd.DataFrame([[0,10],
                       [1,20],
                       [2,30]], columns = ["ID", "new_val"])
```

The final dataframe should thus look something like this:

```
   ID  val  new_val
0   0    5       10
1   1   10       20
2   2   20       30
3   0   10       10
4   1   20       20
5   2   30       30
```

The mapping function should simply look at the value of the ID Column in `df` and assign a new column based on the value which is given in `df_map`

Probably this can be done with a combination of the `.groupby` and `.map` functions in pandas, but I have yet to figure out how.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn’t it `df1.merge(df2, on='ID', how='left')`?

Comment: Thanks for the help. While this did work for the specific case I provided, it turned out to be very slow when iterating over multiple columns of my dataset. I ended up using Daniel's answer becuase it was much faster.

Comment: Point of merge is that you don’t have to iterate over different columns. Otherwise, map usually works faster when you have unique ID in second dataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['new_val'] = df.ID.map(df_map.set_index('ID').squeeze())
```

**Output**

```
   ID  val  new_val
0   0    5       10
1   1   10       20
2   2   20       30
3   0   10       10
4   1    0       20
5   2   15       30
```

Notice that [squeeze](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.squeeze.html) in  `df_map.set_index('ID').squeeze()` converts the DataFrame into a Series.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I chose your answer over Quang's comment because this is much more time efficient.